# Use MySQL functions in Sqoop free-form query

Tags: mysql, etl, sqoop

I'm trying to execute a query like this

```
SELECT replace(name, '\0', '') FROM example
```

using the argument --query in sqoop

```
--query "select replace(name, '\\0', '')" from example e
```

but this approach is returning the error

```
ERROR tool.ImportTool: Imported Failed: No column by the name namefound while importing data; expecting one of [id, REPLACE_name___0_____]
```

Any idea of how to solve this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you need to enclose the SQL statement properly. Then you need to escape "\" character with "/".

Please check below worked for me:

```
sqoop import \
  --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
  --username=retail_dba \
  --password=cloudera \
  --query "select replace(department_name, '/\0', '*') from departments  where 1=1 and \$CONDITIONS" \
  --split-by "department_name" \
  --target-dir "/km/op_sqoop/dept_names" \
  -m 1
```

eval also worked:

```
sqoop eval \
  --connect "jdbc:mysql://quickstart.cloudera:3306/retail_db" \
  --username retail_dba \
  --password cloudera \
  --query "select department_id, department_name, replace(department_name, '/\0', '*') from departments"
```

I didn't get your error though. Hope it helps.